# terraform warning must use splat syntax is annoying

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

Hi I am new to terraform and I am getting the following warning on my project when i run plan/apply.

Warning: output "cloudfront_distribution_id": must use splat syntax to access aws_cloudfront_distribution.cloudfront attribute "id", because it has "count" set;

Comment: What have you done to attempt to fix this yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually a warning when you are using count to define the number of a specified resource you intend to create. 
Use `aws_cloudfront_distribution.cloudfront.*.id` to obtain a list of the attributes across all instances

Example

```
output "cloudfront_distribution_id" {
  value =  "${join("", aws_cloudfront_distribution.cloudfront.*.id)}"
}
```